# Regex working in Regex101 not in R

Tags: r, regex

Here is my regular expression:
https://regex101.com/r/UjWanf/1

```
(^\d+?\.?\d{0,2})([A-Za-z]+|\s[A-Za-z]+)
```

Escaped for R:

```
"(^\\d+?\\.?\\d{0,2})([A-Za-z]+|\\s[A-Za-z]+)"
```

Everything seems to be working fine in regex101 but when I apply the same pattern using strapplyc function in R, it does not capture the entire string.

Example strings:

```
50ml tomato sauce
5g chillies
5 Units tartar sauce
0.25 Units pasta sauce
```

I want to pick up 50ml, 5g, 5 Units and 0.25 Units respectively.

In R, when I apply the pattern in the regex link above using `strapplyc` from the library `gsubfn`, my output is 50m, 5g, 5 U, 0.25 U. Here is a sample of my code:
    a=c("ingredient1", ingredient2", "ingredient3", "ingredient4")
    b=c("50ml tomato sauce", "5g chillies", "5 Units tartar sauce", "0.25 Units 
    pasta sauce")
    consolidated <- data.frame(a,b)`

```
library(gsubfn)
pattern_reg2 <- "(^\\d+?\\.?\\d{0,2})(\\s?[A-Za-z]+)"
consolidated$c <- strapplyc(consolidated$b, pattern_reg2) 
#c column with the desired results
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to escape all those `\ `

Comment: I have done that. The equivalent expression in R - "(^\\d+?\\.?\\d{0,2})([A-Za-z]+|\\s[A-Za-z]+)".

Comment: What package is `strapplyc` from?

Comment: It is from the library "gsubfn"

Comment: Edit your question to include the needed `library` calls and show how you are calling `strapplyc`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with `strapplyc`, but it looks like it's not working properly. Have you tried using R's base regex functions?

```
library(RCurl)
#Load this webpage into a string so I can match the patterns you listed
test_file <- getURL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798279/regex-working-in-regex101-not-in-r")
rgx = "(\\d+?\\.?\\d{0,2})([A-Za-z]+|\\s[A-Za-z]+)" #removed the ^ to allow whole string matching
rgx_result <- gregexpr(rgx,test_file)
result <- regmatches(test_file, rgx_result)
result[[1]][317:321] #only the answers from the strings you were asking to match
```

returns:

```
[1] "50ml"     "5g"       "5 Units"  "25 Units" "50ml"
```

And that works properly. Is there any reason you needed to use `strapplyc`?

Added example for working in a list:

```
test_list <- list('50ml tomato sauce','5g chillies',
           '5 Units tartar sauce',
           '0.25 Units pasta sauce')
for(i in 1:length(test_list)) {
    rgx_result <- gregexpr(rgx,test_list[[i]])
    print(regmatches(test_list[[i]], rgx_result))
}
```

I'm sure this can be done more cleanly with an `apply` function, but I'm just not very good with those.

Comment: Thanks Martin. This works perfectly fine. The only reason I was using strapplyc was that I could use a single command line on my column in the dataframe. But of course, using your solution is straightforward as well.

Comment: Oh no problem, I added an example with a for loop for a list, just treat the column as a list. Instead of printing those values, you can assign them to another column in your `data.frame` if that's your intention.